# G2O BlockSolver Initialization Crash on Unix System

Tags: c++11, unix, unique-ptr, g2o

I have a project which possesses and uses G2O library, it runs on both platforms(win/Unix).

***(WINDOW PASSED / UNIX CRASHED)***

We can see in both platforms, these lines:

```
g2o::SparseOptimizer optimizer;
g2o::BlockSolver_6_3::LinearSolverType * linearSolver;

linearSolver = new g2o::LinearSolverDense<g2o::BlockSolver_6_3::PoseMatrixType>();
```

Next steps, in window os we have this:

```
g2o::BlockSolver_6_3 * solver_ptr = new g2o::BlockSolver_6_3(linearSolver);
g2o::OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg* solver = new g2o::OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg(solver_ptr);
```

But Unix system can't compile those lines because it says

> ***my_file_G2o.cpp:*** *In member function 'int *Refiner_G2O::refinePose(cv::Mat&, const std::vector >&, const std::vector&, const cv::Mat&, float, std::vector&)':* **my_file_G2o.cpp** **--> no matching function for call to** *'g2o::BlockSolver::BlockSolver(g2o::BlockSolver::LinearSolverType*&)'*
>   ^ 
>   In file included from *G2o/include/g2o/core/block_solver.h:199:0*,
>   G2o/include/g2o/core/***block_solver.hpp:40:1***: **note: candidate:** g2o::BlockSolver::BlockSolver(std::unique_ptr) [with Traits = g2o::BlockSolverTraits<6, 3>; typename Traits::LinearSolverType = g2o::LinearSolver >]
>    BlockSolver::BlockSolver(std::unique_ptr linearSolver)

When I see these errors, I complete my Unix code with this new block

```
auto solver_ptr = g2o::make_unique<g2o::BlockSolver_6_3>(linearSolver); // [SEGFAULT LINE]
auto solver = g2o::make_unique<g2o::OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg>(solver_ptr);
optimizer.setAlgorithm(solver.get());
```

So now, I can build/run but I meet a segfault on the line with **[SEGFAULT LINE]** tag.

**EDIT: After step to step debug with debug build I have a few news pieces of information:**

```
g2o::SparseOptimizer optimizer; // debug says: "optimize: g2o::SparseOptimize
g2o::BlockSolver_6_3::LinearSolverType * linearSolver = NULL; // debug says : linearSolver: NULL
linearSolver = new g2o::LinearSolverDense<g2o::BlockSolver_6_3::PoseMatrixType>(); // debug says:  linear solver: 0x7fe39cba9140

if (linearSolver == NULL) // debug says : not null.
    exit (84);
auto solver_ptr = g2o::make_unique<g2o::BlockSolver< g2o::BlockSolver_6_3 >>(linearSolver);
```

// DEBUG --> And here, with "step into" he go to this "/usr/include/c++/6/bits/move.h"
and in the ligne 48 we can see this function:

```
`template<typename T, typename ...ArgTs>
 std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(ArgTs&& ...args) //DEBUG says: args#0: 
 -var-create: unable to create variable object.
  {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(g2o::make_unique<T>(std::forward<ArgTs> 
    (args)...));
   };`
```

And he segfault because she have a bad args.

I don't understand, why? if someone has an idea I want to understand how in Window it works and not in Unix system, will feel wonderful if you help.

LINUX Version: Ubuntu 16.04
CMAKE Version: 3.11.4

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

G2O optimise:

```
g2o::SparseOptimizer optimizer;

auto linearSolver = std::make_unique<g2o::LinearSolverDense<g2o::BlockSolver_6_3::PoseMatrixType>>();

auto solver = new g2o::OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg(std::make_unique<g2o::BlockSolver_6_3>(std::move(linearSolver)));

optimizer.setAlgorithm(solver);
```

MISC.H:

```
template<typename T, typename ...ArgTs>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(ArgTs&& ...args)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<ArgTs>(args)...));
};
```